# Excel - Conditional Format Left and Right Gradients Independently?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on an Excel sheet for Pokémon types.

One part of the sheet allows you to pick the Pokémon type. Cells `B3` and `C3` allow the type to be picked from a drop-down list of types via data validation. See below.

[image]

There is another part of the sheet which combines this type into a single cell with the following formula (which works fine):

```
= IF(OR(C3=B3,C3="(none)"),B3,B3&"/"&C3)
```

In this case, the formula above would return `Grass/Poison`.

This is all well and good, but I want to take this cell and conditionally format it with a 2-color gradient to reflect the dual typing.

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to have a *separate* conditional formatting rule for *each gradient* color.

In other words, if I have these two conditional formatting rules (shown below), it will apply one or the other, but not both.

[image]

An obvious solution to this problem would be to have a single conditional formatting rule to handle this specific combination. (See below.) Although not fully shown below, the conditional formatting formula for this rule is `=AND(B3="Grass",C3="Poison")`.

[image]

This solution does work. However, considering there are 18 types, this means I would have to make 18^2 = 324 separate conditional formatting rules for this cell (to handle all possible type combinations) which, I doubt Excel supports that many conditional formatting rules for a single cell and even if it did, it would be way too tedious to integrate.

If there is a way to have a cell apply two gradient rules to one cell, however, the number of rules would only be 18*2 = 36 (18 for the left gradients, and 18 for the right gradients), which is manageable.

Does anyone know how to have a conditional formatting rule apply a gradient color to only half of the cell (and allow the other half of the cell to be changed by another conditional formatting rule with a gradient)? Is this possible?

Comment: Are all the items in the two dropdowns the same?

Comment: Yes, except for the fact that Type 2 has an extra option of "(none)" as shown in the first image in my post, but why would that matter for answering this question?

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible without VBA.  It isn't possible to create a rule for the format itself, such as If(B2="Grass";"some color").  Because of this, and because you do have 18*18 possibilities, you will need this many conditional rules.  If you can use VBA then this is probably pretty simple.  I suggest a more simple solution and that would be using two cells for your result and applying regular and conditional formatting that would make those two cells appear as one.

Comment: Yes, I thought of using two separate cells side by side. I was trying to be fancy by combining them haha. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This can be accomplished by using VBA I'm sure, I have never tried but VBA should be able to look up in a separate table you would pre-create a RGB color for each value in your dropdown.  You didn't specify VBA so I expected you did not want your users to receive a XSLM workbook.

Comment: And actually, one simple solution to still be fancy, is to simply make the rules all based on your B2 cell and apply a random color as the second half of your gradient.  This way you only need 18 different conditional rules.

Comment: Random color won't work because each type 1 and type 2 has a certain color associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using VBA to add your conditional formatting? I have not heard or experienced a maximum of conditional formatting rules, but I don't claim to be an expert.

The below code will loop through each type and add a conditional formatting rule for your gradient, based on a specified color and type designation. I spot tested it, and it worked for me.

```
Sub CondForm()

Dim colors() As Long
ReDim colors(1 To 18)
    colors(1) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    colors(2) = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    '...Add other types here
    colors(18) = RGB(0, 0, 255)

Dim Types() As String
ReDim Types(1 To 18)
    Types(1) = "Fire"
    Types(2) = "Thunder"
    '...Add other types here
    Types(18) = "Water"

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection

'Remove any previous formatting
Rng.FormatConditions.Delete

For i = 1 To 18
    'Add a rule for the type individually
    With Rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=" & Chr(34) & Types(i) & Chr(34))
        .Interior.Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Interior.Gradient.Degree = 0
        .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).Color = colors(i)
        .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With
    For j = 1 To 18
        'Add a rule for each combined type
        With Rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="=" & Chr(34) & Types(i) & "/" & Types(j) & Chr(34))
            .Interior.Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Interior.Gradient.Degree = 0
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).Color = colors(i)
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color = colors(j)
        End With
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Let me know if this works for you, I'd be curious to hear about the results.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not at all familiar with VBA, I'll give your answer here a shot.

Comment: Enjoy. Let me know if you need any guidance implementing the code. As a side note, I ran a few more tests, and was able to create 4,100 unique conditional formatting rules for one cell. I tried to go higher, but results became unreliable... I suppose long before you reach Excel's maximum, you reach a practical maximum.